# How can i access the functions from other JS files

Tags: javascript

```
(function () {    
    pm.view.functionName= function () {
        function nameFunction() {
          var something;
          return something;
        }    
        return win;
    };
})();
```

I am in another JS file and i want to call this nameFunction()... how can i do this. I tried...

```
pm.view.functionName().nameFunction()
```

But i get an error called, cannot call function in the Object. How can i access the functions from other JS files.

Answer (score 4):

The function `nameFunction` exists in the scope of the function `functionName`.  You cannot access it from outside that function.

If you want to do so, you'll have to explicitly say so:

```
pm.view.functionName.nameFunction = function() {
    var something;
    return something;
};
```

You could then access it as `pm.view.functionName.nameFunction()`.

Comment: when i try pm.view.functionName.nameFunction().. its not getting called i get the same error. i declared your function like this inside my main function.

Answer (score 3):

`nameFunction` is local to `pm.view.functionName` and you cannot access it, just like you cannot access local variables. You can call `nameFunction()` only when being inside `pm.view.functionName`.